# Access to Elastic Beanstalk configuration not possible

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have Elastic Beanstalk instance running PHP 7.4 on Amazon Linux 2 with WordPress which is uploaded as zip. Currently I try to move the instance to private subnet, but I can't access configuration panel of this Beanstalk due to error:

```
A problem occurred while loading your page: Configuration validation exception: 
Invalid option value: '' (Namespace: 'aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:process:default', OptionName: 'MatcherHTTPCode'): 
Value does not satisfy regex: '^(\d{3})([,-]\d{3})*$' [The configured value for 'MatcherHTTPCode' is invalid. A valid value must be a comma separated list of codes (e.g 200,210) or range of codes (e.g 200-210,220).]
```

Right now I'm completely locked out of this Beanstalk config. What can I do to fix this?